# Get array instead of ActiveRecord:Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following rails:

```
ts = Timesheet.select('CASE WHEN price_cents = 0 THEN false ELSE true END as Billable, SUM(time_end - time_start) AS Hours').where(:user => current_user).group('CASE WHEN price_cents = 0 THEN false ELSE true END')
```

This query allows me to get all billable and none billable hours in one go, so performance wise this is perfect.

However it returns

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Timesheet id: nil>, #<Timesheet id: nil>]>
```

It has 2 records with in it the time.  To be able to get the time I need to do:

```
ts.first.hours
```

Is there an easy way to get the billable and the none billable out of ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return an array of `billable` and `hours` as:

```
ts = Timesheet.select('CASE WHEN price_cents = 0 THEN false ELSE true END as Billable, SUM(time_end - time_start) AS Hours').where(:user => current_user).group('CASE WHEN price_cents = 0 THEN false ELSE true END')
ts.map { |t| [ t.billable, t.hours ] }
```

Comment: Works if I put Billable and Hours in lowercase.  Thanks.

Comment: For that given query, `t.Billable` should work.  Can you make sure that `Billable` has upcased `B`.

Comment: Is that the best way to get billable and non_billable hours out?
If I need to display them both in the view that is.

Comment: That question gets the vague answer of "It depends!".  I do like your approach of selecting what is required and passing to the view.

Comment: I definitely want to keep the query. But it's necessary to convert it first into array to be able to get billable and non billable hours out I mean?  BTW doesn't work with Billable, it seems it's automatically down-cased.

Comment: Hash[ts.map { |t| [ t.billable, t.hours ] }] seems to be perfect since then I can easily find billable or not.

Comment: Is your `price_cents` column indexed?  I'm not sure if the `case` statement adds much value there.  I haven't tested this but including `price_cents` in the `select` list might be better in terms of query performance than executing `case...when`.

Comment: No that's not a good idea since price can be anything and I only want two records returned: billable and non billable.  That why I need to group on a case.